# Creating SecKeyRef object via public key on iOS

Tags: ios, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have created a pair of private/public keys using SecKeyGeneratePair. I am successfully able to use the public key to encode and private key to decode. However, I need to save the public key and pass it to another user. That user then needs to create a SecKeyRef object using that public key to encode a text and send it back. I can then use the private key to decode it.

This all works within a single application where the public key and private keys are already loaded in SecKeyRef. I have used the Apple recommended code to get publicKeyBits. But, no matter which I call I have tried, I haven't been successful in creating a SecKeyRef to do my encoding/decoding.

My questions are:

1. How do I save my public key and how do I pass it on?
2. How do I create a new SecKeyRef object using that public key in a new instance of a client?